# Uncaught (in promise): timer after creating SweetAlert2 notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) messages for notification but when this message executed then it is showing error like this in console.

> Uncaught (in promise): timer

here is my alert message

```
swal({
  text: "Your data is being saved",
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1000
}).then(function () {

})
```

Comment: You probably should catch rejections by adding a `.catch()` handler?

Comment: can you put the solution please so i can mark it correct